# How to Display The Description of my Unit Test on TeamCity WebUI?

Tags: unit-testing, build, nunit, automated-tests, teamcity

I'm using NUnit and TeamCity and I have written some system tests with descriptions.

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Should send the password reminder and...
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void ShouldSendPasswordReminder()
        {
}
```

On Teamcity, after a test has run, it displays only the Status, Test Method Name, Test Class Name and Duration; however, I'd like to have the "Description" of the test to be displayed on the TeamCity WebUI as well.

How would that be possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider making the name of the unit test method self descriptive, as described by Roy Osherove:

http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html

This is also described in his book,The Art of Unit Testing, here:

http://artofunittesting.com/

Comment: thanks for your response. I am with you and I have read that book and I have already recommended using proper test method names like your link; however, our team leader has asked for displaying description on TeamCity web ui so I'm looking to see whether it's possible.